Android WebView not able to load shopify checkout
class WebViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityWebViewBinding

    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityWebViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

  
        webView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView)
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()  
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true  
        webView.loadUrl("https://us-xyz-dev.myshopify.com")

        if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
            WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(webView.settings, WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON)
        }
        if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.SAFE_BROWSING_ENABLE)) {
            WebSettingsCompat.setSafeBrowsingEnabled(webView.settings, true)
        }

  
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)

        if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.SAFE_BROWSING_ENABLE)) {
            WebSettingsCompat.setSafeBrowsingEnabled(webView.settings, true)
        }
    }
    override fun onBackPressed() {
      
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

}

This is the WebViewActivity we are using. With this activity, I am unable to load the Shopify checkout page; all other web pages work fine. The Shopify checkout page gets stuck in the loading state, but if I open it in the default Chrome browser, it loads successfully.
I tried to migrate this WebViewActivity from android.webkit.WebView to androidx.webkit.WebView, that also didn't work.shopify checkout on WebViewActivity 
